# After importing a PNG with transparent background it shows up with white background

Tags: apache-flex, png

As the title already states i have a (big) problem importing a PNG in a Flex 4 application.

Created a PNG file in Photoshop with transparent background.
Loaded in Flex application using this code:

```
thumbnailRef.load();
```

thumbnailRef is defined tag based this way:

```
    <net:FileReference id="thumbnailRef"
    select="onBrowseThumbnailRef_select(event);"                           
complete="onBrowseThumbnailRef_complete(event);" />
```

So when the complete event fires the data has been loaded and it is possible to assign the data loaded to the image component named Thumbnail:

```
 private function onBrowseThumbnailRef_complete(evt:Event):void {
                    Thumbnail.source = thumbnailRef.data;
                 }
```

Unitls now everything works as expected!
But when i try to send the Thumbnail component's data to a WCF service i receive a photo with white background:

```
var thumbBitmapData :BitmapData = 
    ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(Thumbnail.content);
    //this is send to the WCF service               
    ThumbnailByteArray = new PNGEncoder().encode(thumbBitmapData );
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're getting the BitmapData using ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData instead of using thumbnailRef.data?

Answer (score 0):

When you use captureBitmapData, it will capture the component but not just the bitmap.  I think you have a white background for the thumbnail component.  If you want to upload the image, you may try the filereference upload.

Comment: I will try to use a transparent background (don't know if this exists) and see what happens...and i will come back!

Comment: The transparent background may not help because it will use the background of the component below the thumbnail component.  But I am not quite sure about that.  You may try.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason:
To be honest, i did play around with thumbnailRef.data. To have control over what is happening i converted the Flex application to an AIR (desktop) application and appended this:

```
Thumbnail.source = thumbnailRef.data;
//reset read pointer
thumbnailRef.data.position  = 0;
var fl:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("test.png");
var fs:FileStream=new FileStream();
fs.open(fl,FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeBytes(thumbnailRef.data);
fs.close();
```

Opening the test.png file on the desktop shows AGAIN a white background! As i understand what i have done is: taking the raw data loaded (which resides in thumbnailRef.data) and saving this data again to the filesystem.

If interpret this correctly this means that the "error" is produced by loading the data, but i don't have any clue how to intercept the loading or controlling it myself (or should i load the data myself...if yes how?).

Weird things....

Comment: My memory is not quite well.  As I remember it is because the alpha channel handling by the flash and something like that.  May be others can tell you more.